# C# Syntax Shortcuts

Tags: c#, syntax, shortcut

I was wondering if there exists somewhere a collection or list of C# syntax shortcuts. Things as simple omitting the curly braces on `if` statements all the way up to things like the `??` coalesce operator.

Comment: This might be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c.  At any rate, you will find a lot of what you are looking for in that post.

Comment: Omitting the curly braces on if statements is not something I consider a good practice. Readability and maintainability are more important than the number of keystrokes. Use snippets or plug-ins like ReSharper to reduce typing.

Comment: I agree with Rick, but if anything, this should probably be a community wiki.

Comment: Thanks for that post Rick, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a = b ? c : d ;
```

is short for

```
if (b) a = c; else a = d;
```

And

```
int MyProp{get;set;}
```

is short for

```
int myVar;
int MyProp{get {return myVar; } set{myVar=value;}}
```

Also see the code templates in visual studio which allows you to speed coding up.

But note that short code doesn't mean necessarily good code.

Answer (score 11):

My all time favorite is

```
a = b ?? c;
```

which translates to

```
if (b != null) then a = b; else a = c;
```

Comment: actually, that would be if b is not null, then a equals b, else a equals c

Answer (score 5):

c# 6.0 has some fun ones. `?.` and `?` (null conditional operator) is my favorite.

`var value = obj != null ? obj.property : null;` turns into

```
var value = obj?.property
```

and

`var value = list != null ? list[0] : null;`

turns into

```
var value = list?[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

How does this C# basic reference [pdf document](http://www.dreamincode.net/downloads/ref_sheets/csharp_basics_reference_sheet.pdf) looks to you?

Here's [another pdf](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/QRC/Core%20CSharp%20and%20.NET%20Quick%20Reference.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I've seen the first one and it has a few examples on there, I was just wondering if there existed a more comprehensive list out there, including some of the not so obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a precompiled list, but the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx) (especially the C# Keywords section) concisely contains the information you're looking for if you're willing to read a bit.

Answer (score 0):

They are not syntax shortcuts, but snippets are great coding shortcuts.  Typing prop (tab)(tab), for example, stubs out the code you need for a property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(VS.80).aspx